# Работа с регулярными выражениями

Tags: .net, регулярные-выражения, visual-c++, c++-cli

Я получаю строку `<image_name>NAME</image_name>`, NAME всегда разное, как мне его выделить в отдельную строку. Видел что использую на `C# Regex.Matches`, но как переделать для с++ не разобрался. Приведите пример, пожалуйста.

```
<status_code>200</status_code>
<status_txt>OK</status_txt>
<data>
    <image_name>O7Q24Hz</image_name>
    <image_filename>O7Q24Hz.png</image_filename>
    <image_type>png</image_type>
    <image_path>/images/2013/10/23/O7Q24Hz.png</image_path>
    <image_url>http://img.chaos-online.ru/images/2013/10/23/O7Q24Hz.png</image_url>
    <image_width>1920</image_width>
    <image_height>1080</image_height>
    <image_attr>width="1920" height="1080"</image_attr>
    <image_bytes>340794</image_bytes>
    <image_size>332.8 KB</image_size>
    <image_thumb_url>http://img.chaos-online.ru/images/2013/10/23/O7Q24Hz.th.png</image_thumb_url>
    <image_thumb_path>/images/2013/10/23/O7Q24Hz.th.png</image_thumb_path>
    <image_thumb_width>240</image_thumb_width>
    <image_thumb_height>135</image_thumb_height>
    <image_id_public>Ix</image_id_public>
    <image_viewer>http://img.chaos-online.ru/image/Ix</image_viewer>
    <image_shorturl>http://img.chaos-online.ru/Ix</image_shorturl>
    <image_delete_hash>3l3xiEayJpXr6oeGLYgkQKuuJA</image_delete_hash>
    <image_delete_url>http://img.chaos-online.ru/delete/image/Ix/3l3xiEayJpXr6oeGLYgkQKuuJA</image_delete_url>
    <image_delete_confirm_url>http://img.chaos-online.ru/delete-confirm/image/Ix/3l3xiEayJpXr6oeGLYgkQKuuJA</image_delete_confirm_url>
    <image_date>2013-10-23 00:32:27</image_date>
    <source>base64 image string</source>
    <resized>0</resized>
    <shorturl>http://goo.gl/3HF2o9</shorturl>
</data>
```

</response>

Comment: а Вы сильно уверены, что это нужно регулярными выражениями парсить? любой вменяемый xml парсер тут сработает на все 100%. Даже на 146%!

Answer (score 3):

Зачем так сложно? Если ваш формат настолько фиксирован, тупо отбросьте первые 12 и последние 13 символов, вот и всё.

Приберегите сложные решения для сложных задач.

---

Если вам на самом деле нужно распарсить XML, то это лучше делать при помощи XML-парсера (неожиданно, правда?).

Что-нибудь наподобие

```
auto xdoc = XDocument::Parse(gcnew String(ваша строка здесь));
// не забудьте оставить в строке корневой элемент
auto imageNameElement = Enumerable::Single(xdoc->Root->Elements("image_name"));
auto imageName = imageNameElement->Value;
```

---

Если вы работаете с нативным C++, вам надо бы использовать стороннюю библиотеку для работы с XML. Поскольку ваш проект получает откуда-то XML, с высокой вероятностью какая-то библиотека уже используется. Если нет, возьмите [любую](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1042855/276994), которая вам нравится. Например, TinyXML.

Comment: Ответ который я получаю содержит много параметров 1 изображения, имя одно из них, мне нужно вытащить 5 параметров оттуда, по этому отбрасывание мне не поможет

Comment: @Zwei, опишите весь формат данных, одна строка или несколько, порядок тегов всегда фиксирован или нет и т.п.

Иначе, боюсь, толкового совета не получите.

А так, смотррите на `man 3 regex, man 7 regex`, IMHO там все подробно описано. Думаю, в винде они д.б. раелизованы.

Comment: @VladD, вообще-то правильно говорит, что XML лучше парсить.

Но, в принципе, если этот XML в одной строке и формат не меняется, то можно, конечно, и по простому, что-то вроде:

    #define TAG "<image_name>"
    char *get_image_name (const char *xml) {
       char *p = strstr(xml, TAG);
       if (p) {
         p += sizeof(TAG) - 1;
         char *q = strchr(p, '<'); // предполагаем, что в теле нет символа <
         int l = q - p + 1;
         char res[l];
         strncpy(res, p, l - 1); res[l - 1] = 0;
         p = strdup(res);
       }
       return p;
    }

Comment: @avp: если формат стабилен, можно упростить, конечно. ТС должен бы уточнить задачу.